# How to pass data to modal from controller in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a controller and i want to send some data from my controller to modal. How can I achive that?
this is my contoller - customers_controller.rb

```
def hours_approved
    @project = Project.find params[:project_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :file => "/customers/hours_approved.js.erb"}
    end    
  end
```

hours_approved.js.erb

```
$('#hours_approved').html("<%= j render partial: 'hours_approved_modal' %>");
$('#hoursapproved').modal('show');
```

this is my modal file- hours_approved_modal.html.slim

```
iv class="modal fade" id="hoursapproved" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"
    div class="modal-dialog" role="document"
        div class="modal-content" style="left:-240px;"
            div class="modal-header" style="padding:0px;"
                h1 Hours Approved
                button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
                span aria-hidden="true" &times;
           div class="modal-body"
               *i want to use here*
```

i want to pass `@project` from controller to my modal 'hours_approved_modal.html.slim' and use this to fetch values.How can I do that?
EDIT 1: if i use this inside my js file

```
$('#hours_approved').html("<%= j render partial: 'hours_approved_modal', projects: @projects%>");
$('#hoursapproved').modal('show');
```

it gives this error-

```
undefined local variable or method `projects' for #<#<Class:0x0055bc4c9b0998>:0x0055bc505bc180>
Did you mean?  @projects
```

**EDIT 2:** this is how i want to use in modal body

```
div class="modal-body"
                 table class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0"
                  thead
                    tr
                      th Project Users
                  tbody
                      - projects.each do |project|
                      tr
                        td = project.name
```

Answer (score 1):

[You must use `locals` to pass the variable along](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

```
render partial: 'hours_approved_modal', locals: { projects: @projects }
```

This way you have access to it in your `.slim` file as `projects`

Comment: its giving the same error: "undefined local variable or method `projects' for #<#<Class:0x0055bc4c9b0998>:0x0055bc4eeefd80>
Did you mean?  @projects"

Comment: How are you using it? Can you [edit] the question with that?

Comment: are you mixing up `projects` and `project`?  it looks like you've only defined `@project` in the controller.  so maybe `locals: { project: @project}` and then use `project` inside the erb partial.  Also @Emu pointed out that the partial name *may* need to be prefixed with a `_`

Answer (score 0):

`$('#hours_approved').html("<%= j render partial: 'hours_approved_modal', projects: @projects %>");`

Now, inside your modal, there is a `projects` variable, which contains the data of `@projects`

Also, please rename your `hours_approved_modal.html.slim` file to `_hours_approved_modal.html.slim` with a `_` in front. Otherwise, it'll not be recognised as a partial.